# How to use Date Picker in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

Please provide me best date picker for mvc4. I don not want to use JQuery date picker.
So if there are any other choice than please let me know.

Comment: Becouse you didn't write browser support, I will tell you "use html5". Why you don't want use jQuery UI one?

Comment: because some time is work perfectly while some time it is not working proper.

Comment: I want to use in IE , chrome and mozila

Comment: In what way is it not working properly?  It may be worth getting to the bottom of the issue your having with the JQuery UI one as it may be (I suspect) that you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Calendar of HTML5 to use this syntax type="date" is a sample:

Reference: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php